# How to output array with new line separated values using Laravel Storage:put

Tags: php, laravel, storage, flysystem

**How to output an each array element in a new line with Laravel Storage:put?**

I have an array like below that I want to put into a file, array_test.txt, where each element goes on a new line.

```
$arrTest
array:2 [
  0 => "Val 1"
  1 => "Val 2"
]
```

Using Laravel's Storage, it goes like `Storage:put($fileName, $arrTest);` However the output is on a single line. Storage as an $options tag, but that seems to just be for setting files as public or private.
If you had a link to what $options could be inputted, I'd like that, I can't find any documentation for what all the $options are for Storage:put!

Another option seems to be using Storage:append($fileName, $arrTest[0]) and then loop over all results.

Is there some easy way to output an entire array's elements on new lines with Storage:put instead of just a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer. You can use `implode` :

```
$arrTest = [
  0 => "Val 1",
  1 => "Val 2"
];
$arrTest = implode("\n", $arrTest);

Storage::put('test.log', $arrTest);
```

Comment: Too bad you can't just have the storage::put method output a new file with lines and need to add \n to the array then convert it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. Hope is helpful.

```
foreach ($arrTest as $index => $arr) {
    Storage:put($fileName, $arr[$index] + "\n")
}
```

Comment: Your code will be useless, because the file will only have values from the last iteration. Also, you forgot `::`

Comment: I think if you changed Storage:put to Storage:append that'll work. Otherwise Storage:put would override the last iteration

Comment: Otherwise. Append it separately & save into the file, than implement the Storage:put